# Multiple data for the IF function

Tags: excel

How can I simplify this formula for huge number of lookup value?

I have two Columns:

```
Column A = Team Name
Column B = Agent Name
```

I want Column A to auto-populate based on the data from Column B. For now, we only have 6 agents, but come August we will have around 300 agents.

So what I need to see is if B2 = "david", a2 should show "Team D", if b2 = "cruz", a2 should show "Team A", if b2 = "dela", a2 should show "team B",etc.

The crucial aspect of this is by August, we will have many agents already so it will be a huge formula. Currently, I'm using the IF function for A2:

```
= IF(B2="David","Team D", IF(B2="Cruz", "Team A", if(B2="Dela", "Team B", "Team C")))
```

Comment: Check out VLOOKUP function.

Answer (score 0):

When you have all the 300 agents, you need to prepare a lookup table with all the agents along with the Team names like below,

[image]

Enter the formula in cell `A2` and drag it down,

```
=VLOOKUP(B2,F:G,2,FALSE)
```